# scroll up the page to the top in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to scroll the webpage to the top of the page.

I know scrolling the page to the bottom is:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)
```

just like that is it possible to scroll the page to the top

Comment: Python: `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0)")`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To scroll to the top of the page, just scroll to the `0, 0`:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Or, as an alternative option, you can [scroll into view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) of the `header` element (or some other element on top):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("header"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

Comment: where did you get the window instance? and for the second approach I'm getting: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"header"}

Answer (score 6):

Use action class, as some UI frameworks don't work well with JavaScript scrollTO

```
actions.sendKeys(keys.Home).build().perform();
actions.sendKeys(keys.END).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution also works correctly, I've checked it:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
    .executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, -document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

Answer (score 2):

To scroll to the top of the page

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollHeight, 0)");
```

To scroll to the end of the page

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can try as below

Way one - Scrolling to bottom of a page

```
driver.navigate().to(URL);
((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

Way two - Scrolling to an element on a page

```
driver.navigate().to(URL);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                "arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

Way 3 -Scrolling by coordinates

```
 driver.navigate().to(URL);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)");
```

Comment: But I want to scroll the page to the top. Here just like (Way one - Scrolling to bottom of a page), I want to scroll the page to the up

Answer (score 1):

simple way for the top :`webDriver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).SendKeys(Keys.Home);`
and for the bottom: `webDriver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).SendKeys(Keys.End);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below solutions.
x-pixels is the number at the x-axis, it moves to the left if the number is positive and it moves to the right if the number is negative .y-pixels is the number at the y-axis, it moves to the down if a number is positive and it moves to the up if the number is in negative .

Scroll Method:

```
executeScript("window.scrollBy(x-pixels,y-pixels)");
```

Sample Code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-5000)");
```

Or you can scroll by using element present on the top of page

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("home"));  
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling is done in the browser and usually has an animation involved. If you need instant scrolling, for example to take a screenshot, use this:

```
window.scrollTo({behavior: "instant", top: 0, left: 0});
```

From Python Selenium driver:

```
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo({behavior: "instant", top: 0, left: 0})')
```